# Luke (in Lucene): How do I change the value of a field?

Tags: lucene, luke

I'm using Luke (for my Lucene index) and I want to change the value of a field.
Perhaps I'm blind, but I simply don't find it where I can do that (ok, I found
out how to add a field, but not change an existing field).

[image: Luke]

Just in case, I can't change a value with Luke, how would I do it?

BTW, can I change the column (field) name, in the screenshot 'bewertung_tl_'?

Thanks,
Bernhard

Comment: Haven't used Luke much in a while, but if memory serves, I think you can update a document in the "Documents" tab.

Answer (score 2):

Note! Backup your index before applying the changes.

There is the Reconstruct & Edit button on the Documents tab. Navigate to the doc in question, click the button and change the field value. It will create a new document in the index with other field values copied and your new value for the field in question. Commit the changes via File->Commit changes. Now on Search tab you may search for the doc id and find two documents matching your criteria. Add another condition with the old field value to narrow down the old document. Press Delete on the Search tab.